# What is this issue with scheduled jobs on UIPath Community edition?

Tags: uipath

I have had a scheduled UiPath job running each 2 minutes for the last few months without any issues. Today, the scheduler does not seem to work at all. I can't seem to find a reason why.

I have tried all of the following:

- Restarted the machine
- Disabled/enabled the scheduled job
- Checked all robot and machine settings in orchestrator
- Check to see that the license status is still OK
- Upgrade studio from 18.3.2 to 19.2.0

We are using the Community Edition Orchestrator and version 18.3.2 community studio. I upgraded to 19.2.0 studio as well, but that did not seem to help. Running the robot from the server manually works when starting a process from the taskbar robot window, but the orchestrator schedules do not seem to be working at all.

Everything seems to set up right considering nothing was changed since this has been running fine for months. It ran well yesterday but simply does not run at all starting this morning. Am I missing something here?

[image: robot orchastrator]

[image: robot on server]

[image: schedule window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a performance issue with UIPath Orchestrator Comunity Edition. There have been issues today according to a few posts on the UIPath forums...

https://forum.uipath.com/t/schedules-no-longer-executing/100553
https://forum.uipath.com/t/robot-isnt-running-as-i-scheduled-on-orchestrator-community-edition/100471/2

Comment: The [answer by UIPath](https://forum.uipath.com/t/orchestrator-schedule-not-working/100561/12) was basically that Community Edition can be unstable and that we should upgrade to a paid license before running any production automation projects. Makes sense I suppose.